# How to provide a python argparse.parser with arguments from inside the code, without command-line arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, argparse

I have a code that takes the command-line arguments into a `parser` and modifies some configuration settings. Something like this:

command:

```
python mycode.py --config-file "some_file.yaml" SOMETHING.subsetting_a 2 SOMETHING.subsetting_b 3
```

and then it does:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Some description here")
parser.add_argument(
    "--config-file",
    default="",
    metavar="FILE",
    help="path to config file",
    type=str,
)
//some more 'add_argument' lines here
args = parser.parse_args()
```

But as I am using jupyter notebook, it would be easier to provide the arguments directly to the parser, as if they come from the command-line. How can I create a string containing the command (as mentioned above) and pass it to `parser`?

Comment: You can also create a `args = argparse.Namespace(config_file='some_file.yaml', ...)` (skipping the `parse_args` step).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`parse_args`'s first optional argument is the list of arguments to parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_args), the signature is:

> `ArgumentParser.parse_args(args=None, namespace=None)`

It just takes `args` from `sys.argv` if you don't provide it.

So just call it as:

```
args = parser.parse_args(['mycode.py', '--config-file', "some_file.yaml", 'SOMETHING.subsetting_a', '2', 'SOMETHING.subsetting_a'])
```

(with the `list` containing whatever you like instead) and it will use it instead of `sys.argv`.

Answer (score 1):

Note: As @ShadowRanger mentioned, there is no need to use `sys.argv`. See his response.

---

One way is to use `sys.argv` to mimic the command-line arguments:

```
import sys

sys.argv = [
    "--config-file" , "some_file.yaml",
    "SOMETHING.subsetting_a" , "2",
    "SOMETHING.subsetting_b" , "3"]

args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv)
```

The content of args is something liek this:

```
> Namespace(config_file='some_file.yaml', opts=['SOMETHING.subsetting_a', '2', 'SOMETHING.subsetting_b', '3')
```

which is similar to the output of `print(parser.parse_args())`.

Comment: You passed non-existent `arguments` to `parse_args`. I think you may have misunderstood the documentation; you could have passed the `list` directly as an argument to `parse_args` instead of modifying `sys.argv` at all.

Comment: That was a typo. Thanks. And yes you are right about not needing sys.argv. I will update it.

Comment: The unit test file for `argparse` tests both a direct list of strings and a doctored `sys.argv`.

Comment: @hpaulj: Yar. It's perfectly legal, the reason not to do it is that you shouldn't be using global state to solve a local problem. The contents of `sys.argv` often mean something, and you shouldn't mess with them willy-nilly if there is *any* other way to accomplish your aims.

Comment: It this case of a jupyter notebook the real sys,argv has already been used by the jupyter server.  So modifying it for 'local' use should be fine - though it may affect other notebooks on the same server.